# File system to use with NAND Flash and 32 bit microcontroller

Tags: nand, nand-flash, filesystem

I am searching for a file system, suitable for NAND flash memory chips. 
Currently I use a Micron 256MB SPI NAND flash memory where I write and read raw sensors data but without a file system and error correction.

So I decided to move to a file system but I don't know where to begin with.
I use the PIC32MX274F256D microcontroller

Now that I also need error correction I decided to move to a suitable file system for NAND. After searching I realized that  it is more dificult than I thought.

If someone has prior experience with NAND flash memory file system or where  to begin with please give me a few hints.

If there is something that I forget to mention please let me know

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. File systems are more of a method, than a product.

Comment: Are you using Harmony to program this, or bare metal? Do you need features like detecting bad blocks? Wear leveling? I'm not sure [YAFFS](https://yaffs.net/) can work with the PIC32, it really depends on how many files you need open at a time. The 274F256D is pretty flash/RAM limited so you may have limited options.

Comment: Hi, I use bare metal design. Yes I need bad block detection and wear leveling especially wear leveling. I want to open only one file at a time

Comment: This is the list with file systems I found that might be suitable (?)
https://github.com/m-labs/rtems-yaffs2/blob/master/README-linux
https://github.com/aviadzuc/NANDFS
https://github.com/bnahill/FLogFS
https://github.com/dlbeer/dhara
https://github.com/ARMmbed/littlefs
https://github.com/rickyzheng/uffs

Comment: I do not know if you are still looking for an answer but I would suggest looking at UBI. http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubi.html  
You might check out the reserved blocks for bad blocks section. Besides of that you can mount a filesystem on top of UBI. Maybe something like SquashFS (very common for embedded devices), depends if you also want a read-only filesystem or not.

Comment: Ok i will check this out. Thank you!